# Azure Mobile Services Table Object Initialization

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I'm working on azure mobile services scripts. While being in insert script code of one table I want to insert a record in another table. I know it is possible using table.insert() function, but I'm not finding out a way to initialize a table object inside the script. The script doesn't recognize the Table name as a type that could be initialized. May be I'm missing some basic point. Following code might help you understand:

```
function insert(item, user, request) {   
Misc misc = new Misc();   // 'Misc' is the table name and it is not recognized as a type.
misc.name = "John";
var tblMisc = tables.getTable('Misc');
tblMisc.insert(misc);
...}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Azure Mobile Services scripting language is Node.js which is dynamically typed, so `Misc misc = new Misc();` won't work.

You could change your first line to:

`var misc = {};`

Or just replace everything with:

`tables.getTable('Misc').insert({ name: "John" });`